# Как правильно передавать данные из репозитария (EF)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеем репозитарий UserRepository, который читает данные из БД, используя `EntityFramework` и сервисный класс `UserService`, который обращается к репозитарию. А наше **UI** уже обращается к этому сервису.

Допустим доменная модель

```
class User { string Name {get; set; }}
```

Каким образом отдавать данные? Неужели в виде доменных моделей?

На ум приходят варианты:

1. Сделать еще один класс `UserModel (UserDto?)`, в котором буду только нужные поля, а в методе репозитария (или в сервисе) преобразовывать доменную модель (простым копированием значений полей). Как вариант, чтобы не копировать данные, `UserModel` может быть потомком `User` (какие сложности вызовет?)
2. Отдавать доменную модель, но предварительно отсоединять ее от контекста.

Comment: у себя в приложении я поступаю по первому пункту, для преобразований в `dto` и обратно использую [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: @Bald как насчет производительности AutoMapper? Не проще ли ручками мапить? Тем более, что Dto не обязательно должен быть точной копией модели.

Comment: насчет производительности не скажу, не тестировал меня все устраивает, некоторые модели я маплю ручками, простые же отдаю на откуп `automapper`. я у себя использую [tag:entity-framewwork] и при помощи *навигационных свойств* делаю следающее например в `Request` есть навигационное свойство `Type`, так вот создав в `dto` свойство: `TypeName` `automapper` в него запишет значение свойства `Name`.

Answer (score 3):

Сущности доменной модели для того и нужны, чтобы работать с ними по всему приложению как с осмысленными единицами информации.
DTO используется в том случае, когда данные, которые вы передаете, не имеют отражения в предметной области. Нет необходимости плодить по два класса для каждой сущности.

В Entity Framework при получении объектов из контекста есть возможность объявлять их неотслеживаемыми.

```
var users = await Context.Users.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Но в этом случае мы получаем зависимость контрактов сервисного слоя от модели хранения данных. При использовании отдельного набора классов для EF я могу хранить данные в более удобном виде (теоретически). Хотя это создаст необходимость поддерживать актуальность модели в двух местах.